# Deserialize XML to same type childs on different elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, collections, deserialization

UPDATE: SOLVED - See below!

When deserializing a xml file containing network nodes there seem to go something wrong when handling child elements.

I've got the following parent (root) class: NetworkCollection

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("networks"), XmlType("networks")]
public class NetworkCollection : CollectionBase, IBindingList
{
  // ...
}
```

With the child classes: Network

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("network"), XmlType("network")]
public class Network
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ...

    [XmlElement("nodes")]
    public NodeCollection Nodes { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("to_add")]
    public NodeCollection NodesToAdd { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("to_remove")]
    public NodeCollection NodesToRemove { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("available")]
    public NodeCollection NodesAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Same for NodeCollection and Node

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("nodes"), XmlType("nodes")]
public class NodeCollection : CollectionBase, IBindingList
{
    // ...
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("node"), XmlType("node")]
public class Node
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("mac_address")]
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
}
```

There are different node types, like this

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("node_type_a"), XmlType("node_type_a")]
public class NodeTypeA : Node
{
    // ...
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("node_type_b"), XmlType("node_type_b")]
public class NodeTypeB : Node
{
    // ...
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("node_type_c"), XmlType("node_type_c")]
public class NodeTypeC : Node
{
    // ...
}
```

The XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<networks>
  <network id="bcb468cac8a34052bf5a5bad8f22d0d7">
    <name>Network Name</name>
    <nodes>
      <node_type_a id="0ac4774277a941228b27d8cfd7ef202e">
        <mac_address>AABBCCDDEEFF</mac_address>
      </node_type_b>
      <node_type_a id="4ca5abb4bb8742c3b321250c20592542">
        <mac_address>BBCCDDEEFFAA</mac_address>
      </node_type_a>
      <node_type_b id="bde044c9aa1948978ba1bc980f00c36b">
        <mac_address>CCDDEEFFAABB</mac_address>
      </node_type_b>
      <node_type_c id="d3f2cb7bd92e4dc89930eeb3cdaeb680">
        <mac_address>DDEEFFAABBCC</mac_address>
      </node_type_c>
      <node_type_c id="039d140b5cc54e06b915b91fb5d8acdf">
        <mac_address>EEFFAABBCCDD</mac_address>
      </node_type_c>
    </nodes>
    <to_add/>
    <to_remove/>
    <available>
      <node>
        <mac_address>FFAABBCCDDEE</mac_address>
      </node>
      <node>
        <mac_address>001122334455</mac_address>
      </node>
      <node>
        <mac_address>112233445566</mac_address>
      </node>
      <node>
        <mac_address>223344556677</mac_address>
      </node>
    </available>
  </network>
</networks>
```

What happens is that every NodeCollection contains one element, so

```
Nodes (1),
NodesToAdd (1),
NodesToRemove (1) and
NodesAvailable (1)
```

all contain one Node object with it's property (MacAddress) set to null;

This should be

```
Nodes (5),
NodesToAdd (0),
NodesToRemove (0) and
NodesAvailable (4)
```

Deserializing the NetworkCollection and Network works fine. It's just about the NodeCollection properties.

Please note the used XmlRoot and XmlType attributes.
The "Id" of the available nodes might be null / missing.

How to deal with this?
Regards

---

OK, i've solved the problem by replacing

```
[XmlElement("nodes")]
public NodeCollection Nodes { get; set; }

[XmlElement("to_add")]
public NodeCollection NodesToAdd { get; set; }

[XmlElement("to_remove")]
public NodeCollection NodesToRemove { get; set; }

[XmlElement("available")]
public NodeCollection NodesAvailable { get; set; }
```

With

```
[XmlArray("nodes")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection Nodes { get; set; }

[XmlArray("to_add")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesToAdd { get; set; }

[XmlArray("to_remove")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesToRemove { get; set; }

[XmlArray("available")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesAvailable { get; set; }
```

Regards.

Comment: Maybe you could post your solution as an answer to your question and then accept it. This makes it more clear to us that this question is answered.

Comment: Hi Thomas W. I've added the solution!.
For some reason SO requires the the question to be at least a day old before you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i've solved the problem by replacing

```
[XmlElement("nodes")]
public NodeCollection Nodes { get; set; }

[XmlElement("to_add")]
public NodeCollection NodesToAdd { get; set; }

[XmlElement("to_remove")]
public NodeCollection NodesToRemove { get; set; }

[XmlElement("available")]
public NodeCollection NodesAvailable { get; set; }
```

With

```
[XmlArray("nodes")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection Nodes { get; set; }

[XmlArray("to_add")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesToAdd { get; set; }

[XmlArray("to_remove")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesToRemove { get; set; }

[XmlArray("available")]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node", Type = typeof(Node))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_a", Type = typeof(NodeTypeA))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_b", Type = typeof(NodeTypeB))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "node_type_c", Type = typeof(NodeTypeC))]
public NodeCollection NodesAvailable { get; set; }
```

Regards.